# Angular6, Test Error , Router

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo los test con Karma v1.4.1 - connected y no pasa el del componente usuario por el router ->

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  public userList = [];
  constructor(private service: DataProviderService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  private getUsers = function () {
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userList = data;
      }, err => {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
    );
  };

  public detailUser(user: any) {
    this.service.userContext = user;
    this.router.navigate(['/detailComponent']);
  };
```

Y su archivo .spect.ts le agregué el Router y el BrowserDynamicTestingModule (este lo leí de otro lado), el caso es que sigue sin funcionar.

```
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataProviderService } from '../data-provider.service';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        // para el router
        Router,
        BrowserDynamicTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [DataProviderService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Chrome 74.0.3729 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 (1 FAILED) (0.454 secs / 0.395 secs)
```

El fallo ->

```
UserComponent should create
Failed: Unexpected value 'Router' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Error: Unexpected value 'Router' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Expected undefined to be truthy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `Router` es parte del módulo `RouterModule`, has de añadirlo a la lista de módulos importados (y no `Router`, que no es un módulo). Pero además, para hacer unit tests, hay que usar un *mock* creado específicamente para esto: `RouterTestingModule`.

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

...
imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    // para el router
    RouterTestingModule,  //AQUI DEBES IMPORTAR El MODULO, NO LA CLASE
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule
  ],
```

Comment: sigue dando error : Error: No provider for Router!

Comment: Corregido, mira a ver si te funciona ahora